# Access an image based on the array index value

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

New to PHP and web-design and playing around with some image based PHP script.

I have been looking around for a way to access a unique image value based on the current array value, but can't seem to find a way of doing it. All the examples I have found have listed the image in the initial array, and then called in in the foreach loop. Is it at all possible to access something without first declaring it in the array? Just trying to avoid double handling since the image(n).jpg will always match the indexed value. i.e. item1 = item1.jpg, item2=item2.jpg and so-on.

Here is my code (I will note the invalid line):

```
$examples = array
(
    'item1' => array
    (
        'title' => 'title of item 1',
        'price' => 'price of item 1',
        'desc' => 'description of item 1'
    ),
    'item2' => array
    (
        'title' => 'title of item 2',
        'price' => 'price of item 2',
        'desc' => 'description of item 2'
    )
);

foreach ($examples as $eid => $example)
{
    echo "<div class='exmple' id='eid_$eid'>";
    echo "<h3>{$exmple['title']}</h3>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<p>{$example['price']}</p>";
    echo "<p>{$example['desc']}</p>";
    //INCORRECT LINE BELOW
    echo '<img src="'.$example['img'].'">'; 
}
```

The incorrect line above is referencing an indexed item:

```
'img' => 'xyz.jpg'
```

that doesn't exist in the initial item1, item2 array.

Is it possible to have the foreach loop create a link to an image based on the current index value? Or do I just add it to the original arrays each line.

Assuming that the file is named correctly. Has a .jpg file extension, and in the same directory the output should look like:

```
<h3>title of item 1</h3>
<p>price of item 1</p>
<p>description of item 1</p>
<img scr="image1.jpg>
```

(Please note, I am not looking to rename any files uploaded, this is all assuming they have been uploaded correctly, in the correct format etc)

Thanks all for the lengthy read!

Edit:

The counter idea is great for incremental increases, but is is possible to identify the image based on the array name/number? i.e. say the two arrays are completely different and non-sequential:

```
'dog56' => array
(
.....
)

'cat72' ==> array
(
...
)
```

This way it finds the dog56.jpg img and then the cat 72 img.

(i.e. the img src is based on the array value)

```
<img scr="dog56.jpg>
```

Kind Regards

Ben S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help and info all.

I was able to come to a solution by replacing my incorrect line with:

```
`echo '<img src="'.$eid.'.jpg">';
```

Now what ever the array item is, the filename it sources will match.

Edit: I can't mark this as "solved" for 2 days sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$i = 1;

    foreach ($examples as $eid => $example)
    {
        echo "<div class='exmple' id='eid_$eid'>";
        echo "<h3>{$exmple['title']}</h3>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<p>{$example['price']}</p>";
        echo "<p>{$example['desc']}</p>";
        //INCORRECT LINE BELOW
        echo '<img src="image'.$i.'.jpg">'; 
    $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $examples = array
    (
        'item1' => array
        (
            'title' => 'title of item 1',
            'price' => 'price of item 1',
            'desc' => 'description of item 1'
        ),
        'item2' => array
        (
            'title' => 'title of item 2',
            'price' => 'price of item 2',
            'desc' => 'description of item 2'
        )
    );
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($examples as $eid => $example)
    {
        echo "<div class='exmple' id='eid_$eid'>";
        echo "<h3>{$exmple['title']}</h3>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<p>{$example['price']}</p>";
        echo "<p>{$example['desc']}</p>";
        echo '<img src="image'.$counter.'.jpg">';

        $counter++; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($examples as $eid => $example)
{
    echo "<div class='exmple' id='eid_$eid'>";
    echo "<h3>{$exmple['title']}</h3>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<p>{$example['price']}</p>";
    echo "<p>{$example['desc']}</p>";
    //INCORRECT LINE BELOW
    $image = 'image'.($eid+1).'.jpg';
    if(file_exists($image)) {
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'">'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image name always matches the array key try this:
`echo '';